# jQuery duplicates click even when DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click

[image: Duplicate Event]

Page load jQuery duplicates click event. When I click once its clicks twice. It's happening for all elements click event in the page. How do I avoid this?

```
$('.dest').click(function(event) {
    console.log('try');
    console.log('try2');
});
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you show us your code, so we would take a look and try to help you?

Comment: hi thank you for answering its happens to every button and anchor tags

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault();` before `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attached screenshot, the assumption that the hyperlink is the element with the *.dest* class, and the observation that the *a* element has sub elements, it seems likely that your click is activating both the *a* element and it's descendants, thus repeating the event listener logic as events bubble up to their parents.

The best practice method to handle this is to set a listener on the document and test the event target to determine if it should fire. Here's an example;

```
   $(document).on('click', function(e) {

    let $target = $(e.target);

    if ( $target.closest('.dest').length ) {

        console.log('try');
     }
   }
```

You can also use event.preventDefault() to prevent the event from bubbling up but this can be problematic when using plugins that look for click events or when setting multiple click handlers, as it will stop the event from bubbling and will not be detected beyond the first handler.